# Not able to install android support repository revision 35

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to upgrade my sdk from command line(Linux). After running

> android update sdk --no-ui

**I can see the package getting downloaded and installed message on the terminal**  but actually it's not getting installed. When I run `android list sdk` command, see the same package available to install as below:

> Packages available for installation or update: 1 1- Android Support
>   Repository, revision 35

Can someone please help me what probably I am missing here? 
Note: I did try `android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1` but same result after installation.